# Joining two networks at two different places with subneting?

Tags: networking, network-shares, lan

How to connect two different networks at different places with 1 server, three hosts, a router and a switch in each network?

Comment: Are the different places geographically separate? In other words, do both sites have too much physical separation to connect them directly?

Answer (score 0):

You need a router between the two networks, and each network needs a static route pointing to the other network via it's respective router interface. I have used OpenVPN in the past to achieve this but it's not for the faint of heart.

However, many consumer-grade internet routers these days have the ability to connect to each other across the internet and route between LANs, you might start looking at your routers to see if they're capable.  If not, new routers which are may the way to go.

Comment: You do definately want some kind of VPN/Tunnel between the endpoints, simply setting up static routes pointing to the other network will not work - you need the "virtual cable" created using a VPN to do this.  OpenVPN rocks, and is probably the simplest solution if your router supports it (which probably means flashing it to use DD-WRT or something like that) !!!